# Find $\lim_\limits{x\to -2}{f(x)}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto{\mathbb{R}}$ be an odd function such that: $$\lim_{x\to 2}{(f(x)-3\cdot x+x^2)}=5$$
Find $\lim_\limits{x\to -2}{f(x)}$, if it exists. (so also prove its existence)

Comment: Well, what have you done so far? What limit theorems do you know?

Comment: @Zardo I have done the following: [here](http://1drv.ms/1IiPjv0), but I think I may have a documentation error somewhere (we need to be strict in Maths).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 2}{(f(x)-3\cdot x+x^2)}=5\\ \lim_{x\to 2}{(f(x)-3*2 +4)}=5\\lim_{x\to 2}{f(x)}=5+2=7\\$$ we know $f(-x)=-f(x)$ as it odd function 
  so $$lim_{x\to -2}f(x)=lim_{x\to +2}f(-x)=\\lim_{x\to +2}(-f(x))=-7$$
  limit exist because :if we have odd function ,domain is symmetrical interval .so if we have $|x-2|<\delta$ around $x=2$  then we will have $|-x-2|< \delta\\or\\|x+2|<\delta$ around $x=-2$
to complete this prove 
$$\forall \varepsilon >0 \exists  \delta >0 :|x-2| <\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-7|<\varepsilon   $$ so $$ \forall \varepsilon >0 \exists  \delta >0 :|x-(-2)| <\delta \Rightarrow |f(-x)-(-7)|<\varepsilon \\\overset{f(-x)=-f(x)}{\rightarrow}\forall \varepsilon >0 \exists  \delta >0 :|x+2| <\delta \Rightarrow |-f(x)-7|<\varepsilon  \\ \space \\ \forall \varepsilon >0 \exists  \delta >0 :|x+2| <\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)+7|<\varepsilon      $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow -2} f(x) =\lim_{x \rightarrow 2} f(-x)=- \lim_{x \rightarrow 2} f(x).$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2} f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 2} 3x-x^2 +5.$$